# I always get an error about call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given, help me

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just started to learn RNN, and I encountered an error, and I don't know the reason why I get the error about **`call()` takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**

code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 128
total_words = 10000
# the max length of sentence is 80, if length of sentence lower than 80, the sentence will be padded.
# If length of sentence more than 80, the sentence will be truncated
max_sentence_length = 80

embedding_len = 100
(train_data, train_label), (test_data, test_label) = tf.keras.datasets.imdb.load_data(num_words=total_words)

word_index = tf.keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()

# set a encode and decode table
# '<PAD>' corresponding to 0, '<START>' corresponding to 1, '<UNK>' corresponding to 2, '<UNUSED>' corresponding to 3
word_index = {key: val + 3 for key, val in word_index.items()}
word_index['<PAD>'] = 0
word_index['<START>'] = 1
word_index['<UNK>'] = 2
word_index['<UNUSED>'] = 3



# truncating and padding the sentence, to realise the sentences have the same length
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, maxlen=max_sentence_length)
test_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data, maxlen=max_sentence_length)

# use shuffle to change the sequence of data
data_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
data_train = data_train.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
data_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_data, test_label))
data_test = data_test.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

```
class TestRNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(TestRNN, self).__init__()
        self.state0 = [tf.zeros([batch_size, units])]
        self.state1 = [tf.zeros([batch_size, units])]

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(total_words, embedding_len, input_length=max_sentence_length)
        self.rnn_cell0 = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units, dropout=0.5)
        self.rnn_cell1 = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units, dropout=0.5)
        self.out_layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = inputs
        x = self.embedding(x)
        state0 = self.state0
        state1 = self.state1
        for word in tf.unstack(x, axis=1):
            out0, state0 = self.rnn_cell0(word, state0, training)
            out1, state1 = self.rnn_cell1(out0, state1, training)
        x = self.out_layers(out1, training)
        prob = tf.sigmoid(x)
        return prob
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    units = 64
    epochs = 20
    model = TestRNN(units)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(data_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=data_test)
    model.evaluate(data_test)
```

> ```
>  error:
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/Users/code/tensorflow24/test.py", line 68, in <module>
>      model.fit(data_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=data_test)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
>      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
>      result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
>      self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
>      self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
>      graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
>      graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
>      func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
>      func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
>      out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
>    File "/Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
>      raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
>  TypeError: in user code:
>
>      /Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
>          return step_function(self, iterator)
>      /Users/code/tensorflow24/test.py:58 call  *
>          x = self.out_layers(out1, training)
>      /Users/tengwang/miniforge3/envs/tf24/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1007 __call__  **
>          outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>
>      TypeError: call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
> ```

Comment: Please add the error message (the full Traceback).

Comment: That's a strange symptom.  The way you've defined your model object looks right, but for some reason, tensorflow is trying to call it with one or more positional arguments that your `call` method isn't expecting.  It's strange that `*args` is being passed to your method, as if that contained any values, you'd expect to get this error.  I don't know enough about tensorflow to know why this is happening.  The only thing I can think of is that you're passing the wrong kind of object for the operation you're asking tensorflow to perform.